# Where are the logs from BackgroundThreads on App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend, background-thread

I'm writing an app that writes log entries from a BackgroundThread object on a backend instance. My problem is that I don't know how to access the logs.

The docs say, "A background thread's os.environ and logging entries are independent of those of the spawning thread," and indeed, the log entries don't show up with the backend instance's entries on the admin console. But the admin console doesn't offer an option for showing the background threads.

appcfg request_logs doesn't seem to be the answer either.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 3):

There is a combobox in the top left corner of the versions/backends of your application switch to the backend there and you will see the backend logs.

Comment: Thank you, Shay. I did check the logs for the backends, looking for the log entries from background threads. What I am finding now is that some entries do indeed show up with the backend's entries, particularly those that are generated because of exceptions or app engine-generated error messages. The log messages generated from app do not appear.